# how to swipe horizontal scroll in browser ionic 3

Tags: css, browser, scroll, ionic3, swipe

I need to scroll a list of images horizontally in ionic v3. I tried using ion-scroll component and works perfect for android platform, but i need same behavior in the browser.

So when I hide the scroll bar it doesn't work, also I tried to set scroll width to 0. Seems that the swipe funcionality only works in mobile devices.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar, *::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    //width: 0 !important
}
```

I need to archive something like [this](https://biobutterfly.com/wp-content/themes/musicapp/pages/index.html).

[image]
I also check ngx-swiper-wrapper library, but i could not get the expected result.

Is there other library that can help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same (horizontal scrolling behavior across all devices and browser) and eventually did this using slider:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#slides

Slides component is based on iDangerous swiper and was made to support coverflow like UIs with multiple slides visible: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/110-slides-per-view.html

Here is simple implementation:

https://ionic-iw4z5s.stackblitz.io